# git create branch in multiple repos

Tags: git, push, putty, private-key

I have many git repositories. I'm writing script which creates **newBranch** from **master** at every repo. So I do this command set for every repo:

```
git checkout master
git branch newBranch
git push origin newBranch
```

I've got problem with last command. It promts password for repo.

Usually I use GitExtension with which works perfect with putty and private key. How can I force 'git push' command to use these settings?

My script will be used by other users with the same CPU configuration, so I need to read this settings automatically.

Comment: This is not a git problem, but a problem with the underlying transport mechanism.  For ssh a typical solution is to delegate to an ssh-agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git Extensions will automatically load the required SSH key into PuTTY’s agent (pageant.exe) for a repo where a private key is specified. If you don’t use Git Extensions you will need to do that manually.

If you set the environment variable `GIT_SSH` correctly to `plink.exe` (Git Extensions should have done that), it will be enough to just launch pageant and load your key into it.